# Excel VBA .Replace not replacing text

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a long array formula, and so i am replacing the condition with "X_X" to avoid the 255 character limit. i also have a predefined variable qbb with the actual length of the array being checked, though for this example, i just set it to 150.
The full formula itself works fine when i add it manually.
The issue is that when i try to do the replacement via VBA, the ".Replace" is not replacing anything. the end result still has the "X_X" and the "114"

```
    Dim frmla As String
    Dim qbb As Variant
    qbb = 150
    frmla = "('Final Summary'!R2C2:R114C2<=R13C4)*('Final Summary'!R2C2:R114C2>=R14C4)*(('Final Summary'!R2C3:R114C3=R10C4)+(R10C4=""""))"
    With ActiveSheet.Range("C16")
        .FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Final Summary'!R2C1:R114C1,SMALL(IF(X_X,ROW('Final Summary'!R2C1:R114C1)-MIN(ROW('Final Summary'!R2C1:R114C1))+1),ROWS(R16C3:RC))),"""")"
        .Replace What:="X_X", Replacement:=frmla
        .Replace What:="114", Replacement:=qbb
    End With
```

I also tried the alternate ".Replace" format:

```
        .Replace "X_X", frmla
        .Replace "114", qbb
```

No luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since `LookAt` will be defaulting to whatever it was last set at, is that `xlPart`, or `xlWhole`?

Comment: in the same macro, i have a previous Find with Lookat:=xlWhole

Comment: but i can set it explicitly if you think that'll help

Comment: Do so.  To replace *part* of the string, like you want to, it needs to be `xlPart`

Comment: interesting. now it replaces the 114 with 150, but leaves the X_X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Range.Replace` needs at least `LookAt` to be set because the settings for LookAt, SearchOrder, MatchCase, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you don't specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. So `LookAt` might be `xlWhole` from saved values.

And `Range.Replace` runs **after** the range contains the formula already. But then this formula will be in `A1` format and not in `R1C1` format when default `Excel` settings are used. So the `frmla` also needs to be in `A1` format and not in `R1C1` format.

```
Dim frmla As String
Dim qbb As Variant
qbb = 150
'frmla = "('Final Summary'!R2C2:R114C2<=R13C4)*('Final Summary'!R2C2:R114C2>=R14C4)*(('Final Summary'!R2C3:R114C3=R10C4)+(R10C4=""""))"
frmla = "('Final Summary'!$B$2:$B$114<=$D$13)*('Final Summary'!$B$2:$B$114>=$D$14)*(('Final Summary'!$B$2:$B$114=$D$10)+($D$10=""""))"
With ActiveSheet.Range("C16")
    .FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Final Summary'!R2C1:R114C1,SMALL(IF(X_X,ROW('Final Summary'!R2C1:R114C1)-MIN(ROW('Final Summary'!R2C1:R114C1))+1),ROWS(R16C3:RC))),"""")"
    .Replace What:="X_X", Replacement:=frmla, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
    .Replace What:="114", Replacement:=qbb, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
End With
```